# Generate random number within specified range without REDUNDANCY in TCL

Tags: random, tcl, ns2

hi I need to generate 30 random numbers without any repeatations of numbers in TCL.

Here is the code to generate random number which works fine, but will generate redundant numbers.

```
proc myRand { min max } {
   set maxFactor [expr [expr $max + 1] - $min]
   set value [expr int([expr rand() * 100])]
   set value [expr [expr $value % $maxFactor] + $min]
return $value
}

for {set i 1} {$i < 31} {incr i} {
upvar 0 fnode($i) fnod($i)
set fnod($i) [myRand 1 20] ;# random number is generated between 1 to 20 
}
```

Anyone please help out.

Comment: Unless float type value, how come you can you generate 30 random numbers within 20 without repetition ? Seems like you are going for integer formatted values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code to generate a sequence of unique random numbers could be written like this, but it won't work unless `$nnums` is less than or equal to `$rmax`.

```
set nnums 30
set rmax 20
set nums {}
if {$nnums > $rmax} {
    puts "You can't get $nnums unique values from a range of 1 to $rmax!"
} else {
    while {[llength $nums] < $nnums} {
        set n [myRand 1 $rmax]
        if {$n ni $nums} {lappend nums $n}
    }
    set nums [linsert $nums 0 {}]
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $nnums} {incr i} {
        set fnod($i) [lindex $nums $i]
    }
}
```

(When I started writing this answer, I was to preoccupied to notice that you were trying to get 30 unique numbers from a 1-20 range, which is impossible, as others have pointed out.)

There are some other problems with your code. You don't need to do nested calls to `expr`:

```
 expr [expr $max + 1] - $min
 # is the same as
 expr {$max + 1 - $min}
```

so your random number generator can be written like this:

```
proc myRand {min max} {
    expr {int(rand() * 100) % ($max + 1 - $min) + $min}
}
```

but that is still more calculations than necessary. This version is better:

```
proc myRand {min max} {
    expr {int(rand() * ($max + 1 - $min)) + $min}
}
```

You can also use this:

```
package require math
::math::random 1 21
```

(Note 21, not 20!)

Answer (score 4):

To generate a list of random numbers without repetitions, you've got to put in code to explicitly prevent them. In general, random sequences most certainly can contain repetitions, just as if you toss a coin, it will sometimes come up heads twice (or more) in a row.

```
set r -1;              # Some value that definitely isn't in the sequence
for {set i 1} {$i < 31} {incr i} {
    upvar 0 fnode($i) fnod($i)
    while {$r == [set r [myRand 1 20]]} {
        # Empty body
    }
    set fnod($i) $r;   # Random number is generated between 1 to 20 
}
```

Note that if you're picking 30 values from a collection of 20 numbers, you'll *necessarily* (by the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)) get some repetitions. But we can prevent values from occurring twice in a row.

---

Your random number generator is slightly horrifying too. This is the idiomatic version:

```
proc myRand {min max} {
    set range [expr {$max - $min + 1}]
    return [expr {$min + int(rand() * $range)}]
}
```